# Access parent variable via child class

Tags: apex

Is it possible to access the variable of a parent class via a child class?. Code example as follows:

```
public class ParentClass {
    private Date creationDate = Date.today();

    private class ChildClass {
        private Date getCreationDate() {
            return creationDate;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but not like that. As written, you're treating the outer class like a **closure**, which Apex does not have.

Your instance of `ChildClass` would need to be holding a reference to an instance of `ParentClass` to access its member variables like that, and the member variable would have to be declared `protected`:

```
public class ParentClass {
    protected Date creationDate = Date.today();

    private class ChildClass {
        private ParentClass myParent;

        private Date getCreationDate() {
            return myParent.creationDate;
        }
    }
}
```

See [Access Modifiers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm):

> `private`
>
> This is the default, and means that the method or variable is accessible only within the Apex class in which it is defined. If you do not specify an access modifier, the method or variable is private.
>
> `protected`
>
> This means that the method or variable is visible to any inner classes in the defining Apex class, and to the classes that extend the defining Apex class. You can only use this access modifier for instance methods and member variables. Note that it is strictly more permissive than the default (private) setting, just like Java.

Answer (score 4):

You can access a parent's `protected` or `private` variables if those variables are declared as `static`. Without the `static` keyword, you'll need a reference to an instance of the class, instead of a `static` reference to the class itself.

```
public class ParentClass {
    private static Date creationDate = Date.today();

    private class ChildClass {
        private Date getCreationDate() {
            return ParentClass.creationDate;
        }

    }
}
```

You could also try doing some layering with interfaces. Children of an `virtual` class can access `private` or `protected` variables inside the parent class.

```
public virtual class ParentClass {
    protected Date creationDate = Date.today();

    private class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
        private Date getCreationDate() {
            return creationDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to "hardwire" the relationship between classes that are not nested.  This is especially useful for scenarios where you want to have several levels of nesting, such as a serializable DTO structure.  But Apex only allows one level.  Doing something like this will predictably result in a null reference exception:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public Date creationDate = Date.today();
}

public class ChildClass {
    private ParentClass myParent;

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return myParent.creationDate;
        // ^^ NULL reference exception here
    }
}
```

A workable solution is to pass the parent in the constructor of the child, which seems janky but definitely works:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public Date creationDate = Date.today();
}

public class ChildClass {
    private ParentClass myParent;

    public ChildClass(ParentClass parent) {
        myParent = parent;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return myParent.creationDate;
    }
}
```